# Finding fragment in a string (a href) with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following snipped:

```
<a href="$click_tracking_url$&landing_url=someurl" border="0" alt=""></a>
```

What i want is just the `someurl`. However there are variations such as following:

```
<a href='$click_tracking_url$&landing_url=someurl' border="0" alt=""></a>

<a target=blank href="$click_tracking_url$&landing_url=someurl" alt=""></a>
```

I had this regex but doesnt work for variations:

```
<a href=\".*?landing_url=(.*?)\">
```

how can i fix it or if there is an easier way to do it?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: You forgot to match things before href. Try this `<a[^>]*?landing_url=([^"]*?)"'. Escape `"` for Java.

Comment: Ilya and SuzanCioc are both right.  You should only use regex on HTML strings if you're absolutely sure that it's going to come in only one specific format.  Otherwise, use an HTML Parser to do it.  The Regular Expression will just keep growing, and growing, and growing, until you realize that it won't work anyway and have to scrap it for an HTML Parser anyway.

Comment: @SuzanCioc i modified it a lil and worked. can u give it as answer and i ll mark it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not match all the variations because you did not consider the attributes between `href` and `<a`. Try that instead:

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a[^>]+href=[\\'\\\"].+&landing_url=(.+?)[\\'\\\"]");`